# pandas to_sql truncates my data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I was using `df.to_sql(con=con_mysql, name='testdata', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')` to export a data frame into mysql. However, I discovered that the columns with long string content (such as url) is truncated to 63 digits. I received the following warning from ipython notebook when I exported:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:248: Warning: Data truncated for column 'url' at row 3
>   cur.executemany(insert_query, data)

There were other warnings in the same style for different rows.

Is there anything I can tweak to export the full data properly? I could set up the correct data schema in mysql and then export to that. But I am hoping a tweak can just make it work straight from python.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.12.0, when I had the question. I have just upgraded to 0.13.1, the newest version pip install provides. But judging from your answer that would have the same issue with 0.12.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using pandas **0.13.1 or older**, this limit of 63 digits is indeed hardcoded, because of this line in the code: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.13.1/pandas/io/sql.py#L278

As a workaround, you could maybe monkeypatch that function `get_sqltype`:

```
from pandas.io import sql

def get_sqltype(pytype, flavor):
    sqltype = {'mysql': 'VARCHAR (63)',    # <-- change this value to something sufficient higher
               'sqlite': 'TEXT'}

    if issubclass(pytype, np.floating):
        sqltype['mysql'] = 'FLOAT'
        sqltype['sqlite'] = 'REAL'
    if issubclass(pytype, np.integer):
        sqltype['mysql'] = 'BIGINT'
        sqltype['sqlite'] = 'INTEGER'
    if issubclass(pytype, np.datetime64) or pytype is datetime:
        sqltype['mysql'] = 'DATETIME'
        sqltype['sqlite'] = 'TIMESTAMP'
    if pytype is datetime.date:
        sqltype['mysql'] = 'DATE'
        sqltype['sqlite'] = 'TIMESTAMP'
    if issubclass(pytype, np.bool_):
        sqltype['sqlite'] = 'INTEGER'

    return sqltype[flavor]

sql.get_sqltype = get_sqltype
```

And then just using your code should work:

```
df.to_sql(con=con_mysql, name='testdata', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

---

Starting from pandas **0.14**, the sql module is uses sqlalchemy under the hood, and strings are converted to the sqlalchemy `TEXT` type, wich is converted to the mysql `TEXT` type (and not `VARCHAR`), and this will also allow you to store larger strings than 63 digits:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')
df.to_sql('testdata', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Only if you still use the a DBAPI connection instead of a sqlalchemy engine, the issue remains, but this option is deprecated and it is recommended to provide an sqlalchemy engine to `to_sql`.

Comment: I have the same problem in pandas 0.14. And if I understand the code (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.14.0/pandas/io/sql.py#L847) correctly it is still hardcoded to varchar(63). I had to change this to get it working.

Comment: should this be reported as an issue on github? has it been?

Comment: It is only an issue with the deprecated `mysql` flavor using a DBAPI connection, the new implementation with sqlalchemy engines does not have the issue, so I don't think it is worth changing.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @joris's answer, I decided to hard code the change into the panda's source and re-compile.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io
sudo pico sql.py
```

changed line `871`

```
'mysql': 'VARCHAR (63)',
```

to

```
'mysql': 'VARCHAR (255)',
```

then recompiled the just that file

`sudo python -m py_compile sql.py`

restarted my script and `_to_sql()` function wrote a table.
(I expected that the recompile would have broken pandas, but seems to have not.)

here is my script to write a dataframe to mysql, for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlalchemy 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = pd.read_csv('10k.csv')
## ... dataframe munging
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None) # workaround for NaN bug
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/dbname')
con = engine.connect().connection
df.to_sql("issues", con, 'mysql', if_exists='replace', index=True, index_label=None)
```