# column width not sufficient when copying dataframe to sql

Tags: pandas, pymysql

I have the following line in the code that works great!

```
df.to_sql(con=connection, name='my_tbl_name', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

But the problem is that it creates column with varchar(63) and the data is more than 63 bytes long.

I get this warning:

```
/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:134: Warning: Data truncated for column '2' at row 1
  result = self._query(query)
```

How do I make sure that pandas create a table with varchar(255) instead of 63?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you are using a version of pandas >= 0.14, you should use `sqlalchemy` to make the database connection (using a DBAPI connection for mysql is deprecated, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries):

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://....")
df.to_sql('my_tbl_name', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

When doing this, your text column will not be truncated, because the sqlalchemy [`TEXT` sql type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) is used by default. If you want to change this to eg [VARCHAR](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR) with a certain length, you can use the `dtype` argument (but this needs pandas 0.16):

```
from sqlalchemy.types import VARCHAR
df.to_sql('my_tbl_name', engine, dtype={'Col_2': VARCHAR(256)})
```

---

When you are using an older version of pandas, or you cannot use sqlalchemy for some reason, you can see this answer for a workaround: [pandas to_sql truncates my data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676170/pandas-to-sql-truncates-my-data/22685355#22685355)