# Pandas to_sql - duplicated columns not duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

This is not my actual data, just a representation

I'm trying to save a pandas dataframe into a postgres database using "to_sql". When i try to do so, however, i get an error "column "my_column" specified more than once".

Thing is, i've taken some precations because i know i can have duplicated columns in this project.
I'm using this funcion to add counters to repeated columns:

```
def df_column_uniquify(df):
df_columns = df.columns
new_columns = []
for item in df_columns:
    counter = 0
    newitem = item
    while newitem in new_columns:
        counter += 1
        newitem = "{}_{}".format(counter, item)
    new_columns.append(newitem)
df.columns = new_columns
return df
```

So if i have two columns named "my_column_is_ok", using this function gives me:

"1_my_column_is_ok" and "2_my_column_is_ok".

Problem is, when dealing with larger column names, postgres doesn't seem to read the entire name before acusing it as a duplicate.

So if a have this situation:

column A:
"my_column_is_ok_but_it_is_sorta_long"

column B:
"my_column_is_ok_but_it_is_sorta_short"

This error returns something like
"column "my_column_is_ok_but_it_is_sorta" specified more than once"

My counter function doesn't work because theese names are not the same, not in its entirety.

If anyone can help me to understand how to deal with this, i would be very thankful.

Comment: see if this post helps: [column-width-not-sufficient-when-copying-dataframe-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340703/column-width-not-sufficient-when-copying-dataframe-to-sql)